# cocos2d calculate destination point given start point, angle and distance

Tags: cocos2d-iphone

Quick one I think. 2d problem in Cocos2d and xcode.

I have

```
CGPoint currPoint;
float lineLength;
float angle;
```

Now, I need to find the point that is lineLength away from currPoint at angle Degrees.

Tried to search, but the answers i have found aren't quite what I was looking for. Would appreciate anyone pointing out the (I assume) pretty simple math I have overlooked.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

From the top of my head:

```
CGPoint endPoint;
endPoint.x = sinf(CC_DEGREES_TO_RADIANS(angle)) * lineLength;
endPoint.y = cosf(CC_DEGREES_TO_RADIANS(angle)) * lineLength;
endPoint = ccpAdd(currPoint, endPoint);
```

Not sure where the vector points to, if it may be rotated by 90, 180 or 270 degrees. If so, just add/subtract that amount from angle.

Comment: Thank you, that's just what I was after.

Comment: @learnCocos2D : for me it has strange effect when the angle is negative.

Comment: Correction : in my case, I shouldn't make the ccpAdd. Without everything is fine. I can't figure out why.

Answer (score 0):

I lost a lot of time trying to solve this issue. Finally I solved it thanks to accepted answer and finding the proper way to calculate the angle. This is my solution:

```
float angle = atan2(y2 - touchSprite->getPosition().y, x2 - touchSprite->getPosition().x) * 180 / M_PI;
float radiansAngle = CC_DEGREES_TO_RADIANS(angle);

Vec2 endPoint;
endPoint.y = sinf(radiansAngle) * lineLength + touchSprite->getPosition().y;
endPoint.x = cosf(radiansAngle) * lineLength + touchSprite->getPosition().x;
```