# Calculating target point given start point, angle and length GOING TO OPPOSITE DIRECTION

Tags: c++, geometry, cocos2d-x, swipe, angle

I've angle,length of line and start point given and I want to calculate target point to move my object here. I'm following this post and some others:

[cocos2d calculate destination point given start point, angle and distance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13058644/cocos2d-calculate-destination-point-given-start-point-angle-and-distance)

Problem : For the 1st and fourth quadrant , it's giving me correct angle. But for 2nd and 3rd quadrant , it's going exact opposite direction. I couldn't figure out issue. This image may make it clear :

[image]

Green arrows are showing my intended direction and red arrows show where it actually go.

My code so far :

```
    float m = (targetPosition.y - initialPosition.y) / (targetPosition.x - initialPosition.x);
    angle = atan (m) * 180 / PI;
    int lineLength = 200;
    float radiansAngle = CC_DEGREES_TO_RADIANS(angle);

    Vec2 endPoint;
    endPoint.y = sinf(radiansAngle) * lineLength + initialPosition.y;
    endPoint.x = cosf(radiansAngle) * lineLength + initialPosition.x;
```

Answer (score 2):

Notice that in each failure case, the red and green vectors have the same `m`, so *the code can't guess which one you mean*.

You can write some more code to detect the quadrant, and add or subtract π accordingly. Or just use [`atan2`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cmath/atan2/).

Comment: ata2 is also not working.I did like this float                                                       xDiff = targetPosition.x - initialPosition.x;
float yDiff = targetPosition.y - targetPosition.y;
return atan2(yDiff, xDiff) * 180 / PI;

Comment: @Nargis `atan2` does work. Check for your own mistakes and consider what range `atan2`  returns in your language (0..2Pi or -Pi..Pi)

Answer (score 1):

I think your issue is with the periodicity of the tan function. You'll need to calculate which quadrant you're in.

I produced something similar a while back but a little different for openscad. You might be able to adapt it to your need. I highlighted the relevant line. I use asin but similar principles apply.

```
module ql (x1,y1,x2,y2,w,thickness=2){
  length=sqrt(pow((x1-x2),2)+pow((y1-y2),2));
  //Next line corrects the angle for quadrant
  ang=((x2-x1)<0)?180-asin((y2-y1)/length):asin((y2-y1)/length);
  translate([x1,y1,0]){
    rotate([0,0,ang]){
      translate([0,-w/2,0]){
        scale([length,w,thickness]){
          cube(1);
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```